# How to remove <96> from a .txt file

Tags: unicode, vi

I receive a `.txt` file with a lot of `<96>` which should be space instead.

In vi, I have done:

```
:%s/<96>//g
```

or

```
:%s/\<96>\//g
```

but it is still there. I did dos2unix, but it still doesn't remove it. Is it Unicode? If yes, how can I remove it? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a good chance those aren't the four *literal* characters `<`, `9`, `6` and `>`. Instead, they're probably the *single* character formed by the byte `0x96`, which Vim renders as `<96>`.

You can see that by executing (from `bash`):

```
printf '123\x96abc\x96def' > file.txt ; vi file.txt
```

and you should see:

```
123<96>abc<96>def
```

To get rid of them, you can just use `sed` with something like (assuming your `sed` has in-place replacement):

```
sed -i.save 's/\x96//g' file.txt
```

---

You *can* also do this within `vim` itself, you just have to realise that you can enter arbitrary characters with <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd> (or <kbd>CTRL-Q</kbd> if <kbd>CTRL-V</kbd> is set up for paste). See [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Entering_special_characters) for details, paraphrased and shortened here to ensure answer is self-contained:

---

> It is possible to enter any character which can be displayed in your current encoding, if you know the character value, as follows (`^V` means `CTRL-V`, or `CTRL-Q` if you use `CTRL-V` to paste):
>
> - Decimal: `^Vnnn`, `000..255`.
> - Octal: `^Vonnn`, `000..377`.
> - Hex: `^Vxnn`, `00..ff`.
> - Hex, BMP Unicode: `^Vunnnn`, `0000..FFFF`.
> - Hex, any Unicode: `^VUnnnnnnnn`, `00000000..7FFFFFFF`.
>
> In all cases, initial zeros may be omitted if the next character typed is not a digit in the given base (except, of course, that the value zero must be entered as at least one zero).
>
> Hex digits A-F, when used, can be typed in upper or lower case, or even in any mixture of them.

---

The key sequence you therefore want (assuming you want them replaced with spaces) is:

```
:%s/<CTRL-V>x96/ /g
```

Comment: @Chubaka, it's one of the C1 control codes, specifically SPA (start protected area). However, what it is in this particular case is totally up to whatever generated the file. If you don't have any `<97>` characters (EPA = end protected area), that's probably *not* what it is. It could be an EBCDIC `o` for all we know :-)